# Interpreting PCA Output

Tags: pca

I have 40 columns (variables); my PCA output (from Minitab) says PC1-PC14 account for 75% of my variation.  How do I pick/determine which of the (original) variables in each PC column are most important?  I see 5 (original) variables in the PC1 column with high positive values.  So, those five are the most influential in that linear combination.  Do I then look at the PC2 column (and so on through PC14) and pick out the (original) variables with the highest values and say they, too, are important?  I am trying to get the 40 original variables down to their most impactful subset to then do a regression analysis and then use that subset to see the impactful variables' influence on a dependent variable.

Comment: Yes usually you would pick out any variables which look "significant" in each PC and try to interpret the PC based on said variables, for each PC - up to some % explained variance.

Comment: Did you run PCA on correlations or on the original variance/covariance-matrix (in case variables are not standardised)? Note that the latter wouldn't allow you to interpret the loadings in terms of variable importance.

Comment: I ran it on the correlations.

Comment: The aim of finding a "most impactful subset ... for regression analysis" implies a PCA of the regressors alone has, at best, only tangential value.  You should instead be analyzing the regressors *along with* the response.  There are many ways to do so: search our site for "model selection" for some examples.

Comment: Depending on your application, it may be better to use a true feature selection approach that reduces the number of features in the original space, rather than a general dimensionality reduction method that finds composite features which may still require measuring all the raw features in practice. If your 40 features represent costly data, you'd probably prefer to know which handful are directly most important, rather than finding that 30 of them together can be used to make an informative feature.

Comment: @whuber - So you're saying I should include the regressors (the dependent variable) in the PCA analysis?

Comment: The regressors are the *explanatory* variables.  The dependent variable is the *response* that you wish to predict.  There's a basic logical problem with analyzing the regressors alone, no matter what technique you use, because that gives you absolutely no information about how they might be related to the response.

Answer (score 6):

First, high negative values would be just as key as high positive ones.

But, more importantly, I don't think this is a good approach. If you want to use a subset of the original variables in your regression, then there are lots of methods that have been discussed here a lot. See the various questions under the [model-selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection) tag.

The goal in PCA is to reduce the number of variables to a subset that contain as much of the variance in the original data as possible. You could then use those components in a regression, but a better method may be partial least squares.  But neither of these retains the original variables.

But, if you use your method, then you will get a bunch of variables from each component. Two problems arise: 1) If a variable is in two PCs, what do you do?  2) If all different variables are in the PCs, then you wind up with a ton of variables, which is what you wanted to avoid in the first place. (In the extreme case, if it's a fully distinct set of 5 variables in each of 14 components, you would have 14*5 = 70 variables.

Answer (score 4):

The `princmp` function in the R `Hmisc` package is designed to aid in interpreting principal components and sparse PCs.  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/impred#sec-impred-pc) for an example.  The approach is based on stepwise regression to approximate each PC.

Comment: Can I be reading this right?  You are recommending something based on stepwise?

Comment: Don’t faint; I use stepwise regression for mechanistic relationships I.e. where the overall $R^2=1.0$. This process is about decoding or approximating not prediction.

Answer (score 1):

In the question, you ask about how to get variables associated with each PC, but also state that ultimately what you really need is a set of variables to move forward with.

This answer is going to suggest using the [CUR decomposition](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0803205106) to pick a set of variables most strong associated with your first 14 PCs jointly.

The linked method starts by defining what they call "normalized statistical leverage scores", as $\pi_j=\frac{1}{K} \sum_{i=1}^K (v_j^i)^2$, where $v_j^i$ is the $j$th entry in the $i$th PC. $K$ is a hyperparameter telling us how many PCs to look at, but it sounds like you have already settled on 14.

They subsequently propose keeping the variable $j$ probabilistically based on a function of the $\pi_j$. Namely, with probability $\min\{1,c\pi_j\}$, where $c$ is essentially a tuning parameter (though they have suggestions on how to pick it).

(But just between you and me, I prefer to simply keep the variables with the highest $\pi_j$s deterministically rather than randomizing. We can use standard methods, perhaps an elbow plot, to decide how many to keep.)